# Prove that the bases of complimentary subspaces $W\in V$ and $Z\in V$ are a basis for $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W\subset V$ and $Z\subset V$ be **complimentary subspaces**, meaning:

1. $W\cap Z=\{0\}$
2. $W+Z=V$ (every $v\in V$ can be written as $v=w+z$ for all $w\in W$ and $z\in Z$)

I need to prove 2 things:

**(1)** If $w_1,...,w_j$ forms a basis for $W$ and $z_1,...,z_k$ forms a basis for $Z$ then $w_1,...,w_j,z_1,...,z_k$ forms a basis for $V$

**(2)**
$\dim{W}+\dim{Z}=\dim{V}$

I don't know how to prove these. In order to be a basis, the vectors $w_1,...,w_j,z_1,...,z_k$ must be linearly independent. The only way I have "proved" this is by saying $W\cap Z=\{0\}$ implies that $W$ and $V$ span "unrelated" spaces, so since $w_1,...,w_j$ are linearly independent and $z_1,...,z_k$ are linearly independent, then the collection of all $w_1,...,w_j,z_1,...,z_k$ is linearly independent. I don't know how to prove this without words.

For **(1)** I still need to prove $w_1,...,w_j,z_1,...,z_k$ spans $V$ if we assume my explanation above is sufficient to show $w_1,...,w_j,z_1,...,z_k$ are linearly independent

For **(2)** I have almost no idea what to do.

Comment: The words "unrelated spaces" make no sense, so of course this explanation isn't sufficient. In order to show the vectors are linearly independent you should assume that their linear combination is equal to $0$ and prove that all the coefficients must be equal to $0$. Try it. I'll give a hint: first prove that if $z+w=0$ for some $z\in Z, w\in W$ then we must have $z=w=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x_1, ..., x_n$ and $y_1, ..., y_m$ are the respective bases. Showing that they span the entire space together should be trivial and I'll leave it up to you. Linear independence is what you're struggling with?

Suppose there are coeffs such that $\sum a_ix_i  + \sum b_j y_j = 0$; do some rearranging to get $\sum a_ix_i = \sum -b_j y_j$. But the LHS is in $W$ and the RHS is in $Z$, and LHS=RHS which means that $\sum a_ix_i = \sum -b_j y_j = 0$. But by the linear independence of the $x_i$ by themselves and the $y_j$ by themselves, we have that $a_i, b_j = 0$.

Now we have that $\{x_i, y_j\}$ form a basis, which means that $dim(V) = |\{x_i,y_j:i\leq n, j \leq m\} = |\{x_i:i\leq n\}| + |\{y_j:j\leq m\}| = dim(W) + dim(Z)$

Comment: Thank you so very much. This makes sense except the last part, why does $\dim{V}=\{ x_i:i\le n \} + \{ y_j:j\le m \}$ ?

Comment: I think I'm not used to the notation, but anyways, I think **(2)** is obvious since the dimension of $V$ is the number of independent vectors that make up $V$ which is $\dim{W}+\dim{Z}$